# Function Pointer dereferencing, different parameters

Tags: c, stack, function-pointers

I want to create a C module which handles Callbacks:

```
typedef struct {
  int enable;
  void (*callback)(void);
  void *obj;
} Callback;

void Callback_Notify(Callback *me) {
  if (me->enable && me->callback) me->callback(me->obj);
}
```

However, the modules which shall use this Callback module have callbacks with (different) parameters. My current solution is a preprocessor hack (left out the \):

```
#define Callback_Notify1Arg(me, cb_type, arg1)
  if (me->enable && me->callback)
    ((cb_type)me->callback)(me->obj, arg1);

#define Callback_Notify2Arg(me, cb_type, arg1, arg2)
  if (me->enable && me->callback)
    ((cb_type)me->callback)(me->obj, arg1, arg2);
```

Now a module using the Callback looks like the following:

```
typedef void (*SomeModuleCb_t)(int);
typedef struct { Callback cb; } SomeModule;
void SomeModule_DoSomething(SomeModule *me) {
  int someData;
  Callback_Notify1Arg((&me->cb), SomeModuleCb_t, someData);
}
```

The Code works! But I want to know if there is a stack corruption? Does the compiler allocate/deallocate the stack correctly around the Callback usage in SomeModule_DoSomething? For the memory allocation in the Callback struct does the callback pointer's signature matter?

Any better solutions for the topic are welcome!

Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: From your example it is unclear what functions are casted.

Comment: To avoid the casting hack you could defined a separate `Callback;` for each possible function pointer type. Alternatively, you could write thunks (i.e. add a `void(void*)` function for each callback, and in those functions, call the target with the right parameters). The latter is more flexible.

Answer (score 2):

As long as the function pointer was to a function that accepts that parameters, and you cast the function pointer to the original type there shouldn't be a problem. You can cast a function pointer to another function pointer if you cast to the original type before doing the call.